# Dependent checkboxes using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

I've created the following functionality for depending checkboxes:

```
<div>
<input type="checkbox" value="true" class="controller01">
</div>
<div>
<input type="checkbox" value="true" class="controlled01">
</div>
<div>
<input type="checkbox" value="true" class="controller02">
</div>
<div>
<input type="checkbox" value="true" class="controlled02">
</div>
<div>
<input type="checkbox" value="true" class="controlled02">
</div>
<div>
<input type="checkbox" value="true" class="controlled02">
</div>
<div>
<input type="checkbox" value="true" class="controlled02">
</div>
```

and the script:

```
$('.controlled01').prop('disabled', true);
$('.controller01').click(function () {
    var $inputs = $('input:checkbox')
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
        $('.controlled01').not(this).prop('disabled', false);
    } else {
        $('.controlled01').prop('disabled', true).prop('checked', false);
    }
})

$('.controlled02').prop('disabled', true);
$('.controller02').click(function () {
    var $inputs = $('input:checkbox')
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
        $('.controlled02').not(this).prop('disabled', false);
    } else {
        $('.controlled02').prop('disabled', true).prop('checked', false);
    }
})
```

You can check it there: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WFL9q/)

So far, this is working fine, but I am wondering if there is some way to make this script more general. As you can see, for every group of checkboxes (*controller* and *controlled*), I need to have this:

```
$('.controlled01').prop('disabled', true);
$('.controller01').click(function () {
    var $inputs = $('input:checkbox')
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
        $('.controlled01').not(this).prop('disabled', false);
    } else {
        $('.controlled01').prop('disabled', true).prop('checked', false);
    }
})
```

What I would like to have is a script, which can handle for example 01-99 groups, without adding another piece of code to the script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can make some simple markup changes

```
<div>
    <input type="checkbox" value="true" class="controller01 controller" data-target=".controlled01">
</div>
<div>
    <input type="checkbox" value="true" class="controlled01 controlled">
</div>
<div>
    <input type="checkbox" value="true" class="controller02 controller" data-target=".controlled02">
</div>
<div>
    <input type="checkbox" value="true" class="controlled02 controlled">
</div>
<div>
    <input type="checkbox" value="true" class="controlled02 controlled">
</div>
<div>
    <input type="checkbox" value="true" class="controlled02 controlled">
</div>
<div>
    <input type="checkbox" value="true" class="controlled02 controlled">
</div>
```

then

```
$('.controlled').prop('disabled', true);
$('.controller').click(function () {
    var $this = $(this),
        $inputs = $($this.data('target'));

    $inputs.prop('disabled', !this.checked);
    if (!this.checked) {
        $inputs.prop('checked', false);
    }
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/8hBBV/)

Comment: Thanks Arun for quick response. Just two notes: 1. On last line there needs to be "controlled" instead of "controlled01", 2. In this case if I unselect any "controller" id will unselect all "controlled" checkboxes, even they are from different group.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you want something like this:

```
function controlGroups(controller, controlled){
    $(controlled).prop('disabled', true);
    $(controller).click(function () {
        var $inputs = $('input:checkbox')
        if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
            $(controlled).not(this).prop('disabled', false);
        } else {
            $(controlled).prop('disabled', true).prop('checked', false);
        }
    })
}
```

Usage:

```
for(var i=1; i < 99; i++){
    controlGroups('.controller'+i,'.controlled'+i);
}
```